# Social Network "Friend Table" and "Post Table"

Tags: sql

Below are two table of my Social Network Site are: \
1. Friend table
2. Post Table
(Only provide Specimen, I am not authorized to post images)

**Friend Table**

**user_id | friend_id**

```
2     |    1
1     |    2
3     |    1
```

---

**POST Table**

**post_id | user_id | post**

```
1   |    2    |  image.jpg
2   |    1    |  image.jpg 
3   |    1    |  image.jpg
```

According to social media rule on your wall you can see your and your friend post.
Please find sql query to first find user friend(Friend Table),

then,

Extract user and friend post (POST Table) .

I hope that you have given me good and positive reply soon.

Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a query for `user_id = 1` - just replace the id for any other user:

```
SELECT post
FROM   post
WHERE  user_id = 1 OR
       user_id IN (SELECT friend_id
                   FROM   friend
                   WHERE   user_id = 1)
```